# Convert Function into a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert a function into a javascript object but seem to run into an issue along the way please the original code work fine designed to execute using the .each method, calling back the setTranstion function.

However, The new code developed doesn't execute the same. I attempt to turn the original code into a javascript object as a result, I get an undefined variable $selector.

codepen link: https://codepen.io/paul-solomon/pen/yjBEpz

Please see below:

```
    Original Code
    ============================================= 

   //Global Vars
   $HvrContainer = $(".container-hover ,.transition- 
   hover,.transition h3");

   function setTransition(id, prop, delay, style) {
   $(id).css({ "-webkit-transition": prop + " " + 
   delay + " " + style });
   $(id).css({ "-moz-transition": prop + " " + delay 
   + " " + style });
   $(id).css({ "-o-transition": prop + " " + delay + 
   " " + style });
   $(id).css({ transition: prop + " " + delay + " " + 
   style });
   }

   //Module Controller for Sweep Classes
   $($HvrContainer).each(function() {

   $selector = $HvrContainer //Class or Id
   $transition = "all";  //Sets Option for Transition 
   $speed = ".3s"; //Sets Option for Speed  
   $FX =  "ease-in-out"; //Sets Option for Easing   

   setTransition ($selector, $transition, $speed 
  ,$FX);
   });


   New Code 
   ==============================================

   //Global Vars
   $HvrContainer = $(".container-hover ,.transition- 
   hover,.transition h3");

   function setTransition(id, prop, delay, style) {
   $(id).css({ "-webkit-transition": prop + " " + 
   delay + " " + style });
   $(id).css({ "-moz-transition": prop + " " + delay 
   + " " + style });
   $(id).css({ "-o-transition": prop + " " + delay + 
   " " + style });
   $(id).css({ transition: prop + " " + delay + " " + 
   style });
    }

   var fxController = {
   $selector : $HvrContainer,//Class or Id
   $transition : "all",  //Sets Option for Transition 
   $speed : ".3s", //Sets Option for Speed  
   $FX :  "ease-in-out", //Sets Option for Easing 
   $animationFX : function() {
   $($HvrContainer).each(function() {
    setTransition ($selector, $transition, $speed 
  ,$FX);
  })
 }
}
```

fxController.$animationFX();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all Functions in JS are objects, so no conversion needed here. Looking at your code i can tell that you're trying to make object **fxController** that has a method **$animationFX** and that method needs to use **setTransition** function. Inside the method you need to remember about the context, as you a trying to access the properties of the object, you need to address them with **this**(and don't forget to save the context of the object).

So your code will look like this:

```
$HvrContainer = $(".container-hover ,.transition-hover,.transition h3");

function setTransition(id, prop, delay, style) {
$(id).css({ "-webkit-transition": prop + " " + delay + " " + style });
$(id).css({ "-moz-transition": prop + " " + delay + " " + style });
$(id).css({ "-o-transition": prop + " " + delay + " " + style });
$(id).css({ transition: prop + " " + delay + " " + style });
}

var fxController = {
  $selector : $HvrContainer,//Class or Id
  $transition : "all",  //Sets Option for Transition 
  $speed : ".3s", //Sets Option for Speed  
  $FX :  "ease-in-out", //Sets Option for Easing 
  $animationFX : function() {
    $(this).each(function() { //Iterates over the object FxController
      setTransition (this.$selector, this.$transition, this.$speed, this.$FX);
    });
  }
};
fxController.$animationFX();
```

Comment: EddgaPo As your response with the "this" accessing the object seems correct. The function call inside the object method isnt accessing the property and value (eg: $selector : $HvrContainer ) as it renders undefined in codepen. Any more suggestions ?

Comment: my bad, you need to save the context of the object to be able to acces it in the function for each array element, made some fixes

Comment: Not necessarily the case but good idea. I figured out the problem. the issue was that I iterated each array $HvrContainer, which was nested inside the object fxController, that caused the undefinded error because I should have in fact iterated over the object fxController. (example: jQuery.each( object, callback )). see final version